# How to create array of objects within objects for hierarchy javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, object, multidimensional-array, hierarchy

Suppose I have the following mysql table. Different VP's, each having their own Directors,SrManagers,Manager, and list of employees. I need to create an object with a hierarchy to bind all of my dropdowns in my flex application. I need a dynamic way of iterating and creating array of objects within objects. Now I can do a bunch of for loops and get this working, however it was given to me as a requirement that it should be flexible enough that when a new layer is added (for example SuperSeniorManagers above SrManagers). It should be able to detect and adjust. I have a separate table where I store the different hierarchy levels that I can use as a reference when creating objects. Such as;

1. VP
2. Directors
3. SrManagers
4. Manager
5. Employee

I can't seem to be able to create a function that would do this without having to modify the code each time. I am using actionscript, however if your solution is javascript that should be fine too. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
+----------------+-----------+------------+-----------+------------+
| VPs            | Directors | SrManagers | Managers  | Employees  |
+----------------+-----------+------------+-----------+------------+
| VP1            | Director1 | SrManager1 | Manager1  | Employee1  |
| VP1            | Director1 | SrManager1 | Manager1  | Employee2  |
| VP1            | Director1 | SrManager1 | Manager1  | Employee3  |
| VP1            | Director1 | SrManager1 | Manager2  | Employee4  |
| VP1            | Director1 | SrManager1 | Manager2  | Employee5  |
| VP1            | Director1 | SrManager2 | Manager3  | Employee6  |
| VP1            | Director1 | SrManager2 | Manager3  | Employee7  |
| VP1            | Director1 | SrManager2 | Manager3  | Employee8  |
| VP1            | Director1 | SrManager2 | Manager3  | Employee9  |
| VP1            | Director2 | SrManager3 | Manager4  | Employee10 |
| VP1            | Director2 | SrManager3 | Manager4  | Employee11 |
| VP1            | Director2 | SrManager3 | Manager4  | Employee12 |
| VP1            | Director2 | SrManager4 | Manager5  | Employee13 |
| VP1            | Director2 | SrManager4 | Manager5  | Employee14 |
| VP1            | Director2 | SrManager4 | Manager6  | Employee15 |
| VP2            | Director3 | SrManager5 | Manager7  | Employee16 |
| VP2            | Director3 | SrManager5 | Manager7  | Employee17 |
| VP2            | Director3 | SrManager5 | Manager8  | Employee18 |
| VP2            | Director3 | SrManager5 | Manager8  | Employee19 |
| VP2            | Director3 | SrManager5 | Manager8  | Employee20 |
| VP2            | Director3 | SrManager6 | Manager9  | Employee21 |
| VP2            | Director3 | SrManager6 | Manager10 | Employee22 |
| VP2            | Director3 | SrManager7 | Manager11 | Employee23 |
| VP2            | Director3 | SrManager7 | Manager11 | Employee24 |
| VP2            | Director3 | SrManager7 | Manager11 | Employee25 |
| VP2            | Director4 | SrManager8 | Manager12 | Employee26 |
| VP2            | Director4 | SrManager9 | Manager13 | Employee27 |
+----------------+-----------+------------+-----------+------------+
```

Comment: What kind of object are you trying to build (I'd guess { something: [ like: { ... }, this: { ... } ] }, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Iserni If you go this link you will a snippet of my code of what I am currently doing. You will notice that I have to manually create a lot of objects and do a lot of checks to make sure I put the right person in the right place. http://chopapp.com/#kvy9vt2   I need a more flexible solution like I mentioned before in case I need to add another layer... Thank you.